# canDeactivate issue with Angular material dialog (used as child component)

Tags: angular

Am using CanDeactivate guard for alerting user about the pending changes, which works fine except the below scenario:
Simulation: 1. Go to the main page.
2. Click the button -> Opens angular material dialog.
3. Do some edits and switch the navigation to another route on main menu.
**Result->** 1. Pending changes alert comes with exit or continue option.
2. click on Continue -> Stay w/o route switch.
3.click on Exit-> Navigate to new route..However by **DIALOG REMAINS OPEN..!!** (Need to close separately).

```
 contactDetails(){
    const dialogRef = new MatDialogConfig();
   // dialogRef.disableClose = true;
    dialogRef.autoFocus = true;
    this.dialog.open(ContactinfoComponent, dialogRef);      
    }


export class ContactinfoComponent implements OnInit {    
  disableSave: boolean | true;    
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ContactinfoComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)) { }    
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  submit() {
    }  
  onNoClick(): void {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

Note, this is an entry component in the module, so i cant associate guard using routes. Have tried to implement guard seperately on modal dialog, still no use.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.
Thanks 
ASJ

Comment: I don't understand how you can "switch the navigation to another route on main menu" while a modal dialog is opened. If it's opened, and you can still click on your navigation menu, then it's not a modal dialog.

Comment: Somehow my dialog is not showing full modal behaviour. My boortstrap modals are behaving the way you mentioned..But over there i had same pblm with browser back button when modals are opened(goes to new route while notification modal remains open).Thatz the reason i made a trial to try material dialog. code invoking dialog / dialog component are already enclosed..may be i have done something wrong..!